How to remove nullable fields from veevalidate and valibot in vue3
I've got vue3 form with veevalidate and valibot to validate that form.
<script setup>
import { useForm } from 'vee-validate';
import { object, optional, string, minLength, number, nullable, nonNullable } from 'valibot';
import { toTypedSchema } from '@vee-validate/valibot';
const {
        values,
        defineField
    } = useForm({
        validationSchema: toTypedSchema(
            
                object({
                    name: string([minLength(1))]),
                    reference: string([minLength(1)]),
                    price: optional(nullable(number()))
                })
            
        ),
    });

    const [name] = defineField("name");
    const [reference] = defineField("reference");
    const [price] = defineField("price");
</script>
<template>
<form>
    {{ values }}
    <input type="text" v-model="name" />
    <input type="text" v-model="reference"  />
    <input type="text" v-model="price" />
</form>
</template>

In values we have returned fields.
If i have insert and then remove price i've got null in that field.
{
  name: 'some name',
  reference: 'reference code,
  price: null
}

But i want to remove null and undefined fields. I don't want to send null fields to backend.
Expected results:
{
  name: 'some name',
  reference: 'reference code,
}

Question is how to achieve this in useForm/validationSchema?
